How to make a Python Dataclass mixin?
To make a dataclass in Python you typically use the decorator. Something
like:
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo:
    n: int = 1

    def bump(self):
        self.n += 1

Alternatively you can use make_dataclass to do something
like
Foo = make_dataclass('Foo',
                   [('n', int)],
                   namespace={'bump': lambda self: self.n += 1})

Is there a way to make a mixin class, say Dataclass, so that you
could write the first form as follows?
class Foo(Dataclass):
    n: int = 1

    def bump(self):
        self.n += 1

Or is there a reason why that might be undesirable?

No, there isn't. One major reason it wouldn't be desireable is because that isn't how dataclasses work. The dataclass code generator isn't a base class, a "dataclass" isn't a type. It's a code generator to avoid boilerplate. Although, that actually has a precedent in the Python source code with typing.NamedTuple, see this answer and the question to see what I mean by it being misleading

You might want to use Pydantic lib, so you can inherit from BaseModel, which is "Dataclass on steroids"

It depends on what you want the mixin to do and what version of python you are on. As of python 3.11, you can declare a class decorated with @dataclass_transform, and subclasses will then be treated similarly to a dataclass by type checkers/language servers, in that they will typehint calls to the class’s constructor with any class attributes/defaults declared in the class. But dataclass_transform will not automatically generate a constructor or other magic methods the way the @dataclass decorator does.  You would have to implement all the dataclass logic yourself in the base class.
